# swf loading on top of each other in flash

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, image-gallery

I have a flash file, (banner ad) and i need to have an image gallery and an flv player, which i have. to save space i've used a loader to call them via their swf file using a button. but when i do this it calls the swf on top of my main flash page constantly layering more and more pages on top of each other.

heres is my loader code:

```
var loadedSWF:Loader = null;
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("imagegallery.swf");
loadedSWF = new Loader();
loadedSWF.load(req);


function loadSWF(file:String, container:MovieClip=null):void
{
if(container == null) container = MovieClip(root);

// removes the previously loaded SWF
if(loadedSWF != null)
{
    if(loadedSWF.parent) loadedSWF.parent.removeChild(loadedSWF);
}

addChild(loadedSWF);
}
imageGallery_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _click);
function _click(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  loadSWF("imagegallery.swf");
}
```

It's some code i found on this website.

[image: heres an image of the problem:]

Comment: What would you like to do? You can position objects by giving them x/y coordinates. You can change their width/height. You can open a new browser window. You can push other content down or hide it... And so on. When you're done with things you can remove them. Please clarify what you're trying to do and someone can help.

Comment: i just want it to load up in replace of the one before, either by removing it, also when i click the back button i want the swf file i loaded to go, which it doesn't. i.e. my main fla is called 1 and i want to be able to load 2 swf called A and B, when i click a button. so when the button for A is click i want it to replace the fla file 1 and then when i click the back button i want the swf file to be removed from screen. sorry if i didn't describe it very well.

Comment: also i cant have it opening in a separate browser page, i do know how to do that

Comment: Don't automatically add all the files when they are loaded, but instead add them to an Array or Vector and then go back and forth between them either on a timer or with a next/previous button (by removing the previous one and adding the next one).

Comment: how exactly would i do that, I'm playing around with different ways atm to try stuff out.